# VS2005 not attaching to aspnet worker process

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging

When I start a debug session in VS2005 (to debug an ASP.Net web site), The browser is launched but the Debug session ends. VS is not attaching to the worker serive. I can attach manualy to aspnet_wp service and then debug.

Before I not my new works PC this happend automatiacly now its a manual task.

What have I done or forgotten to do?

In the past I have never had to do anything for this, just standard installs which i was I thought I had done

Thanks

J

Comment: Is debug set to true in web.config? Is the browser being served by IIS Service installed on the PC or ASP.NET Dev Server? See the start up settings for the project.

Comment: Debug is True
Browser is using IIS on PC (windows XP Pro)
Startup settings in project select custom server http://localhost/... etc

The project does work on other PC's just not my new one....

Thanks

Comment: On my old PC this worked fine, Its only happend since I installed new dev PC. Ive been doing this for years and this is the fist time its happend. I just cant see what the difference between the 2 install are. all looks the same.

Its just that on old PC the debug session is started and atteches to the asp worker process.

the new pc the debug session looks like its going to work, but does not attach to the worker thed, we page is show in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that integrated windows authentication is enabled for the web site/virtual directory. This can be in addition to anonymous authentication since that always takes precedence. Visual Studio requires it to be turned on to debug.

Comment: Yes windows Auth is configured

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're configured to use the Visual Studio Developer Server, not IIS. Did a little icon show up in the tray area? Check the "Web" tab of your project properties.